# Why do I get negative temperature values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem with my code. I want to get average temperature for the city of Kiev, but I get negative temperature values for all seasons and I don't know why. It's nothing wrong with the conversion from fahrenheit to celsius.

Here is the code:

```
# Selecting temperature data from Kiev

kiev_df = df[df["City"] == "Kiev"].copy()

# Converting fahr to celsius
kiev_df = fahr_to_celsius(kiev_df)

# Converting "dt" column to datetime format
kiev_df.loc[:, "dt"] = pd.to_datetime(kiev_df["dt"], format="%Y%m%d")

def get_season(month):
    """
    
    Dividing months into seasons.
    
    Parameters: month (int): Month number (1 for January, 2 for Februrary, etc.)
    
    Returns: 
    str: The season corresponding to input months.
    
    """
    if month in [12, 1, 2]:
        return "Winter"
    elif month in [3, 4, 5]:
        return "Spring"
    elif month in [6, 7, 8]:
        return "Summer"
    else: 
        return "Autumn"

# Map get_season function to the month of each date in "dt" column
kiev_df.loc[:, "Season"] = kiev_df["dt"].dt.month.map(get_season)

# Group data by year and season, calculate the mean of temp data
seasonal_avg = kiev_df.groupby([kiev_df["dt"].dt.year, "Season"]).agg({
    "AverageTemperature": "mean" ,
    "Tuncertainty": "mean"
}).reset_index()
                                        
seasonal_avg.columns = ["Year", "Season", "AvgTemperature", "AvgUncertainty"]

print(seasonal_avg)
```

I try to get average temperature for all seasons, but I get negative values and that is not correct.

And here is the code for convertion

## Creating function to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius

```
def fahr_to_celsius(df):
"""
Converts Fahrenheit temperature to Celsius (excluding the "Tuncertainty" column)

Parameters:
- df (DataFrame): DataFrame containing temperature data.

Returns:
- DataFrame: A modified DataFrame with temperature columns converted from Fahrenheit to Celsius values.
"""

# Converting these columns from fahr to celsius
celsius_conv = ["TMAX", "TMIN", "AverageTemperature"]

for col in celsius_conv:
    df[col] = (df[col] - 32) / 1.8

return df
```

Here is a sample of the data:

```
    dt  AverageTemperature  Tuncertainty    City    Country TMAX        TMIN
114929  17440401    49.676      4.4964      Kiev    Ukraine 54.1724     45.1796
114930  17440501    55.6556     3.321       Kiev    Ukraine 58.9766     52.3346
114931  17440601    63.3074     3.0654      Kiev    Ukraine 66.3728     60.242
114932  17440701    66.9002     2.8656      Kiev    Ukraine 69.7658     64.0346
114933  17440801    -9999       2.9466      Kiev    Ukraine 68.28430418 63.60738403
```

Comment: please share some data as well.

Comment: "It's nothing wrong with the conversion from fahrenheit to celsius." Can you include the definition of `fahr_to_celsius()` anyway?

Comment: dt AverageTemperature Tuncertainty City Country TMAX  TMIN
114924 17431101 33.611  3.7656  Kiev Ukraine 37.3766 29.8454
114925 17431201 -9999  3.91176  Kiev Ukraine 27.8785749 21.61635437
114926 17440101 -9999  4.05792  Kiev Ukraine 23.65778792 16.99335925
114927 17440201 -9999  4.20408  Kiev Ukraine 25.39187955 19.22479318
114928 17440301 -9999  4.35024  Kiev Ukraine 33.88834943 28.42255774

Comment: It looks like your input data *has* negative values, likely in place of missing data. The `-9999`, for example.

Comment: before the conversion to celsius, filter the values less than -459.67
or
after the conversion to celsius, filter the values less than -273.15

Comment: Post the data in the question, not comments, so you can format it properly

Comment: If your sample data a before or after conversion to Celsius?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample similar to your data:

```
s = pd.Series([49.0, 55.5, 63.0, 66.9, -999])
```

What do you expect the `mean()` of `s` to be with data like this? Of course it's negative, the absolute value of `-999` is an order of magnitude larger than the other values, so it will affect the average most.

As with all ETL tasks, you need to clean your data to extract meaningful information out of it. Inspect your data *manually* and decide what values should not be taken into account, and then filter them out before statistical analysis.

Do you think that a temperature of `-999` is a sane value for temperature in Ukraine, whether Fahrenheit or Celsius? Assuming the laws of thermodynamics have not been broken, I think it's safe to filter those out.

```
>>> s = pd.Series([49.0, 55.5, 63.0, 66.9, -999])
>>> s.mean()
-152.92000000000002
>>> s[s > -999].mean()
58.6
```